# Using Shuffle(); with all photos

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page that has a lot of photos on it. I am going to shuffle them using the shuffle();

But you would have to use this.

```
$images = array
(
'/images/carousel-1.jpg',
'/images/carousel-2.jpg',
'/images/carousel-3.jpg',
'/images/carousel-4.jpg',
'/images/carousel-5.jpg',
'/images/carousel-6.jpg',
);

shuffle($images); // the magic

foreach ($images as $image)
{
echo '<div class="image-entry">';
echo "\t" . '<img src="' . $image . '" />';
echo '</div>';
}
```

And the HTML;

```
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-5.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-entry">
        <img src="/images/carousel-6.jpg" />
    </div>
```

(This could go on for hundreds of photos)

Instead of doing an array for every single one, Is there a way i can call for all of them in a short code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$images = glob('/images/carousel-*.jpg');
```

to create an array with all matching filenames (see [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)), or use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to create a range of filenames:

```
$images = array_map(
    function($n) {
        return "/images/carousel-$n.jpg";
    }, range(1,10)
);
```

Comment: So if I put all my photos in  the file /Photos/Home/ 
would I do  $images = glob('/Photos/Home/');?

Comment: Something like `'/Photos/Home/*'`, `'/Photos/Home/*.jpg'` or `'/Photos/Home/carousel-*.jpg'` would work better. See [glob (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) on Wikipedia.